# Непонятные символы в ответе на запрос

Tags: запрос, php, c++

Всем привет. У меня есть запрос к некоторому PHP файлу. Скрипт в этом файле печатает некоторые данные, например:

```
printf("E1");
printf("OK.%d", $id);//например OK.342
```

И у меня есть с++ WinHttp клиент, который умеет получать ответ от скрипта. К сожалению, ответ не является "E1", вместо этого приходит

```
"п»їE1"
"п»їOK.342"
```

У меня нет мыслей почему так происхоит. Также, я написал РНР скрипт для тестирования, который получает "Е1" без этого мусора. Кто-то может помочь разобраться?

upd. Попробовал менять кодировки PHP файла. Без изменений, кроме UTF-8:

```
"п»їп»їE1"
```

И никакой разницы с UTF-8 (w/o BOM) и ANSI

Comment: я может что-то не понимаю, но с ANSI - та же песня

Comment: поставил кодировку этого файла и файла dbconnect.php (который инклудится в скрипт) на ANSI и проблема исчезла. Почему?

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Смотрите не редакторами/IDE, которые эти символы могут съедать, а чем-то более подходящи, начиная с hex-вьюверов (да хотя бы Shift+F3 в Midnight Commander/FAR) и заканчивая банальным `cat myfile.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ищите utf-bom в файлах

Comment: Ребята, спасибо вам и коллегам с stackoverflow
Перевел в UTF-8, действительно есть три символа (использовал для перевода Notepad++)
Удалил, все работает, всем спасибо